# Passing user input data from view to controller via AJAX in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to send drop-down list data from view to controller via AJAX as a form variable using post method.

I am able to send the drop-down list data from view to controller using get method and using route parameters.

Here is my view code snippet:

```
function drawChart(frmyear, toyear) 
{

    console.log(frmyear);
    console.log(toyear);


        var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "get_salesthree/"+ frmyear + "/"+ toyear +"/",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false
                    }).responseText;

        console.log(jsonData);
```

Route code snippet:

```
    Route::get('get_salesthree/{frmyear}/{toyear}', array('uses'=>'Analytics\DashboardController@get_salesthree'));
```

For security reasons I don't want to pass user input data using route parameters. Also I have multiple user input parameters which needs to send to controller hence above method is not feasible as well. Hence any other alternative solution available in this case?

Controller code snippet:

```
public function get_salesthree($frmyear, $toyear)
{   

     return \Response::json(Salethree::get_formatted_salesthree($frmyear, $toyear ));

}
```

Dropdownlist code snippet:

```
<label>From Date</label>
                    <select id="ddlfrmyear" name="frmyear" onchange="check(this);">
                    <option value="-1">Select Date </option>
                        @foreach ($date_lists as $date_list)
                    <option value="{{ $date_list}}">{{ $date_list}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
```

JavaScript check function:

```
function check(sel) 
{
   document.getElementById('ddltoyear').disabled = !sel.selectedIndex;
   var frmyear =  document.getElementById('ddlfrmyear').value;

   var toyear =  document.getElementById('ddltoyear').value;

   console.log(frmyear);    
   console.log(toyear);
    if (toyear != '-1')
    {
        drawChart(frmyear, toyear);
        //drawChart();      
   }
}
```

Now I am getting check function is not defined after changing ajax call as suggested. I am wondering what it the relation between on-select event of drop-down list and AJAX route?

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example for your understanding, I hope this will guide you to get your functionality.

if you don't want to show your data/parameter in URL, then you can also use Ajax Post,

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST' 
        url: "get_salesthree/",
        data: yourForm.serialize()
        dataType: 'json'
```

and in your routes, remove variable for query string, and make it like this.

```
Route::post('get_salesthree/', array('uses'=>'Analytics\DashboardController@get_salesthree'));
```

and in your controller

```
public function get_salesthree(Request $request){   
     $frmyear = $request->input('frmyear');
     $toyear  = $request->input('toyear');

     //do your functionality as per your need


     return \Response::json(Salethree::get_formatted_salesthree($frmyear, $toyear ));

}
```

Comment: I tried your suggested approach and included ajax method as suggested but due to this I got function not defined (actually this is javascript function which is called on OnSelect event of dropdownlist). I wonder why this function is not getting executed on selection of dropdown as I just changed ajax only.

Comment: Why dont you convert your pure Js code to Jquery standards? It will help you to debug your code.. 2ndly console.log your code and check that at which location its breaking

Answer (score 0):

Try this jquery answer:

js:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
 var frmyear =  $('#ddlfrmyear').val();
  var toyear =  $('#ddltoyear').val();

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST' 
        url: "get_salesthree/",
        data: {frmyear:frmyear ,toyear:toyear},
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data){
          console.log(data);
        }});
  });
```

laravel:

```
Route::post('get_salesthree/', function(Request $request){

 $frmyear = $request->input('frmyear');
  $toyear  = $request->input('toyear');

     return \Response::json(Salethree::get_formatted_salesthree($frmyear, $toyear 

});
```